# How do these technologies go together?

Tags: web-development, ruby-on-rails, front-end

- Ruby on Rails
- Twitter Bootstrap
- Html5Boilerplate
- Backbone.JS or Knockout.JS

I sort of understand what each one is individually, but my understanding isn't strong enough to understand whether some of them sort of overlap in functionality and whether any subset of that list contains items you wouldn't use together because they play similar roles. I'm fairly clear on RoR-- it's mainly the latter three that I'm not sure how they play together.

Comment: My favorite thing about stackexchange is unexplained downvotes. They really add to the ambiance.

Comment: It's kind of a requirement, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you are asking for the contact points between these technologies.
any answer trying to thoroughly answer that question might fill a book.
So, in order to get you going I have made a somewhat simple illustration, it shows a high-level overview:

[image: overview]

you see that I have changed [`Html5Boilerplate`](http://html5boilerplate.com/) to simple HTML because Html5Boilerplate has a quite some overlap with backbone/knockout and bootstrap (contains its own javascript and css) and does not play particularly well with rails either.
therefore, it does not seem a fortunate fit in this combination.

However, with some effort you can use Html5Boilerplate or any other library or framework that produces Html in that position (see [this guide](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-html5-boilerplate.html) for using html5boilerplate with rails).